# FATAL EXCEPTION: main / android.view.InflateException

Tags: java, android, exception, android-viewpager

im trying to create a ViewPager for my app. Im new to android developing so first im trying a sample to look how it works from [this](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537) site. 
When i try to run it in the emulator it force closes. I dont know why i get the error, i checked the code lot of times and there is no difference.

So as the code is the same as in the link above i only provide the logcat.

```
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testviewpager/com.testviewpager.TestViewPagerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePagePageIndicator
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePagePageIndicator
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at com.testviewpager.TestViewPagerActivity.onCreate(TestViewPagerActivity.java:14)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     ... 11 more
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePagePageIndicator in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.testviewpager-1.apk]
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
01-30 04:07:40.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3013):     ... 20 more
```

The com.viewpagerindicator is a libary project (on the link its com.jakewharton.android.viewpagerindicator, i know that, i just changed it to the original), there i changed nothing, only imported from the authors site.
So if anyone know what i did wrong please help. I can provide more information if this is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem but i figured out that the solution very simple if you are following [this link](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537)  like me you have to delete this part [jakewharton.android] from your main layout refering to link main layout this what causing inflateException and make it just like what your viewPagerIndicator library package name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you are either importing or linking the library correctly.

Here is a post that shows an easy example of how to import a similar type lib and link it up.

[using-the-johannilsson-android-actionbar-library](http://mobile.cs.fsu.edu/using-the-johannilsson-android-actionbar-library/)

I have made a view pager myself, but did not end up using this library.
Instead I used the android support package. It works much better for me because I do not have to import the entire package, I just have to link the lib.

[compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)

Comment: I've done the same, so it looks like it works, i can use the methods and everything.
I dont know maybe i will try the support package but im curious what i did wrong.

Comment: Linking can be a little tricky sometimes. I've also found myself desperately hitting the clean button in hopes that will fix stuff. I believe the main reason you need to import the project as opposed to linking up the jar is because you need access to the resources for some reason. I.e like editing your facebook buttons and stuff like that.

Either way, I'm glad you got everything working :)

Comment: Sorry for my english you misunderstand me, so it looks like it works, no error etc, but i cant run the app, i tried using maven, or just importing it, no errors but cant access the classes from the libary project.
The support package is working, but there is no title indicator, and i cant write one myself.

Comment: Ok. If your trying to use the viewpagerindicator as in https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/SampleTabsDefault.java it still appears that your imports are not correct in that case. You'll have to follow the steps in the first link I provided. Just use the viewpagerindicator instead of the action-bar. Don't forgot to clean the project after you import, sometimes that helps

Comment: thanks for your help, but i found some other solutions which worked perfectly