# How to solve android.view.InflateException when using com.android.internal.widget.NumberPicker?

Tags: android, widget, customization, numberpicker

I'm using [this blog](http://devmobapps.blogspot.de/2011/09/numberpicker-use-and-customization-of.html) to create a custom Number Picker.
I've added this source project to my Eclipse but when I run this project in emulator I get this error in LogCat.

```
10-14 15:31:46.074: E/AndroidRuntime(878): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
activity ComponentInfo{maximyudin.NumberPickerDemo/maximyudin.NumberPickerDemo.NumberPickerDemo}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.NumberPicker
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="maximyudin.NumberPickerDemo"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="15" android:minSdkVersion="8"></uses-sdk>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".NumberPickerDemo"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Have you seen this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386116/fatal-exception-main-android-view-inflateexception

Comment: I finally used [this blog](http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5) to create custom number picker.It worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. `com.android.internal.widget.NumberPicker` does not support in Android 2.2 and later. I tried to run [this example](http://devmobapps.blogspot.de/2011/09/numberpicker-use-and-customization-of.html) in Android 2.2 and caused the error that I mentioned on my question.
This is the main.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<com.android.internal.widget.NumberPicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/numTestNumberPicker"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
</com.android.internal.widget.NumberPicker>
```