# com.android.internal.widget.NumberPicker with Android API 17

Tags: android, android-widget, numberpicker

Hello i've been looking for a specific numeric input view and i found it in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523510/is-there-a-view-for-inputing-integers-in-android), but when i tried to implement the solution proposed by Will, i faced this exeption

```
android.view.InflateException
```

after some research , i tried this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882828/how-to-solve-android-view-inflateexception-when-using-com-android-internal-widge) , but the same error still persists,is it true that `com.android.internal.widget.NumberPicker` does not support in Android 2.2 and later?? isn't there something that replace it ? or something that looks like it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not inflate anything in `com.android`. You have no idea whether that exists on any given Android device. Please note that the StackOverflow question and answer you cited is from **2009**, which is very old for Android advice.

[`NumberPicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) was added to the Android SDK back in API Level 11. [Here is one backport](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker) of it to older devices, though it is not currently maintained.

Comment: Thank u for the answer , but i'm really newbie in Android , and i don't know what should i declare in my xml file to get  NumberPicker ?? i downloaded the zip file , i thought it's a jar but i found a source code!!

Comment: @BelSam: A search for `android numberpicker (example OR tutorial)` on a major search engine turns up pages like [this](https://shanetully.com/2011/12/android-3-x-and-4-x-numberpicker-example/) and [this](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/numberpicker.php) and [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2078060&seqNum=2) and many others.